# How to get the third wednesday of given year from edittext?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to make a app where the user puts a number(year)in edittext and when you click the button the user gets in a textview the third wednesday of april from that year. For example they put 2020 and get as a result the date 15.04.2020. that was the third wednesday of april in 2020. I have an edittext, a button and a textview. Thank you for helping.

Problem solved thank you:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `LocalDate` with `TemporalAdjuster`

Use [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation [`TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth(int,java.time.DayOfWeek)).

Parse your textual input of year number to an `int` using `Integer` class.

Get the first day of your specified year as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object.

```
Year y = Year.of( 2021 ) ;
LocalDate startOfYear = y.atDay( 1 ) ;  // First day of the year.
```

Move to April. Using [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so we get a new fresh object rather than alter ("mutate") the original.

```
LocalDate ld = startOfYear.with( Month.APRIL ) ;  // Move to the first of April, our desired month.
```

Get a temporal adjuster implementation for the 3rd Wednesday of the month.

```
int ordinal = 3 ;  // Third such day of the month.
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ;
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( ordinal , dow ) ;
```

Apply the adjuster to get another `LocalDate` object, our desired result, the third Wednesday of that month.

```
LocalDate thirdWednesdayOfApril = ld.with( ta ) ;  // Move to the 3rd Wednesday of April of the specified year.
```

To generate text in a certain format for presentation to the user, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-). Search to learn more, as this has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Ok now it shows for any year I put in edittext the 3. wednesday of April from 2021 but only for 2021. If I want the 3. wednesday of April say for 2025, what can I do sothat after putting 2025 in edittext and clicking button the textview will show automatically the correct date of 3. wednesday of April from 2025? Or any other year I put in edittext.

Comment: @zam93 I don’t understand your comment. Seems obvious that you would pass the desired year to `Year.of` as seen in my code.

Comment: My question is how can the value of Year.of() get changed automatically by the user. When Year.of(2021), now the user has no Code but only the edittext for typing a number. If the user puts the year 2025 or another year in edittext and clicks button then the value of year.of should change automatically to 2025 or what ever is put in edittext.

Comment: @zam93 As I said in the Answer, you get the user’s text entry, parse it with `Integer`, and pass the resulting `int` to `Year.of`. That’s rather obvious, basic programming, so perhaps I am still not understanding your issue.

Comment: How can I send the date I have now in textview to the android calendar app by clicking a new button? For example I have the date of thanksgiving for 2021 in a textview and now I want to save that date to my local calendar outsite my app.